# Cannot save variable text to file

Tags: php

I am having a problem with this code:

```
$myvariable = "<?php $user_id = '5'; ?>";
```

...now I then write it to file using php...

and this is what I see when I open the saved file:

```
<?php  = '5'; ?>
```

$user_id is missing!

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: PHP will parse the variables in `"` quoted strings, which will happen before you *save string to file* action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use double-quotes, any `$variables` in the text will be replaced with their *current* value. Because `$user_id` isn't defined in the code that's currently running, it's replaced with nothing.

There are a couple of ways to prevent this from happening.  You could wrap your string in single-quotes instead, escaping the existing single-quotes in the text with a backslash:

```
$myvariable = '<?php $user_id = \'5\'; ?>';
```

Or you cou could instead escape the `$` with a backslash, so that it's not interpreted:

```
$myvariable = "<?php \$user_id = '5'; ?>";
```

Comment: They could also escape the `\$user_id` using `"`, right? (See: http://codepad.org/xrZUBeXU)

Answer (score 2):

PHP interprets variables within strings if you surround the string with double-quotes, as you are using.  If you use single-quotes, however, it interprets the string literally.

Try escaping the dollar sign in the variable name.  Like this:

```
$myvariable = "<?php \$user_id = '5'; ?>";
```